# Mac keyboard shortcut to strip special characters and search selected text in youtube

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Often I will look at a podcasts tracklist and identify the songs I would like to download. My process looks something like this:

1. Go to tracklist page
2. Select a song name (which on the occassion has underscores / hyphens instead of spaces)
3. Switch to my YouTube tab
4. Paste the text
5. Remove any special characters such as underscores and/or hyphens
6. Search

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut that would take my selected text, strip out any special characters (mostly concerned about hyphens and underscores), and create a YouTube search for it in a new tab. I am on Mac OS X 10.6 and use FireFox for the most part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greasemonkey might be able to help you out here, or you may like to use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void(window.open("http://www.youtube.com/results?aq=f&oq=&search_query="+window.getSelection().toString().replace(/\W+/g,'+')));
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed. Now for mozilla to make mac keyboard shortcuts work with firefox...

Comment: hm how can I change it to remove anything in parenthesis, including the parenthesis. Ex: "(Something / Here)Lorem_Ipsum" would do a search for "Lorem Ipsum".

Comment: Well, you can do basic parenthesis removal using another .replace clause, but you have to decide whether you have to worry about multiple or mismatched parentheses... a simple version would be to do `.replace(/\\(.*\\)/, '+')`